# How can i replace the image in pictureBox1 with a crop image of a drawn on the pictureBox1 rectangle area?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

First i'm drawing a rectangle on the pictureBox1 with the mouse

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        rect = new Rectangle(e.X, e.Y, 0, 0);
        painting = true;
    }
}

private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        rect = new Rectangle(
            rect.Left, 
            rect.Top, 
            Math.Min(e.X - rect.Left, pictureBox1.ClientRectangle.Width - rect.Left), 
            Math.Min(e.Y - rect.Top, pictureBox1.ClientRectangle.Height - rect.Top));
    }
    this.pictureBox1.Invalidate();
}

private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (painting == true)
    {
        using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 2))
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, rect);
        }
    }
}
```

The variable rect is global Rectangle and painting is global bool.

Then I did inside the pictureBox1 mouseup event

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.Image = SaveRectanglePart(pictureBox1.Image, rect);
}
```

And the method SaveRectanglePart

```
Bitmap bmptoreturn;
public Bitmap SaveRectanglePart(Image image, RectangleF sourceRect)
{
    using (var bmp = new Bitmap((int)sourceRect.Width, (int)sourceRect.Height))
    {
        using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
        {
            graphics.DrawImage(image, 0.0f, 0.0f, sourceRect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        }
        bmptoreturn = bmp;
    }

    return bmptoreturn;
}
```

What i want to do is when i finish drawing the rectangle in the mouseup event to clear the pictureBox1 and replace the image in there with the rectangle image only.

But i'm getting exception parameter not valid in the mouseup event

```
pictureBox1.Image = SaveBitmapPart(pictureBox1.Image, rect);
```

And should i dispose somewhere the variable bmptoreturn ?

Answer (score 1):

In the function `SaveRectanglePart` the variable `bmp` is `Dispose` of before the function returns as a result of the `using` statement. You need to remove the `using` statement and the code should work.

```
Bitmap bmptoreturn;
public Bitmap SaveRectanglePart(Image image, RectangleF sourceRect)
{
    var bmp = new Bitmap((int)sourceRect.Width, (int)sourceRect.Height)
    using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
    {
        graphics.DrawImage(image, 0.0f, 0.0f, sourceRect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
    }
    bmptoreturn = bmp;

    return bmptoreturn;
}
```

But we have the issue of what `bmptoreturn` and `pictureBox1.Image` were referencing before they were set. The old `Image`/`Bitmap` the reference will be lost in memory until garbage collection comes along to free their memory. To be a good programmer we need to `Dispose` of these `Image`/`Bitmap` when we are done with them.

```
Image tmp = bmptoreturn;
bmptoreturn = bmp;
if(tmp != null)
    tmp.Dispose();
...
Image tmp = pictureBox1.Image;
pictureBox1.Image = SaveBitmapPart(pictureBox1.Image, rect);
if(tmp != null)
    tmp.Dispose();
```

Also, I am not sure why you are using `bmptoreturn` but it is not needed in the code from what I can tell. You can simply return `bmp` if `bmptoreturn` is not being used elsewhere.

Comment: KDecker I tried the code now I changed the method SaveRectanglePart according to your solution and using only bmp now. And in the mouseup event I added the code with the Image tmp = pictureBox1.Image;....and the ret but what it does is like zooming the image the rectangle. It's not replacing the rectangle part but making zoom in.

Comment: @DanielVoit From what I can tell from the question "to clear the pictureBox1 and replace the image in there with the rectangle image only." this is exactly what you want to do.